# Evaluating a floating point variable in Scheme language

Tags: variables, types, scheme, lisp

I want to read multiple data files (10 in total) in Ansys Fluent. I wrote a journal file which uses scheme language

```
(Do ((count 11.100 (+ count 0.100))) ((>= count 12.000))
(ti-menu-load-string (format #f "file read-data data-~a.dat" count)))
```

The format of the file name is like `data-11.200.dat`, but the program reads it as `data-11.2.dat`. How I can force it to read the floating point numbers after the decimal point?

Of course I can rename the data files, but that is not useful for I have to use the code many times.
I have tried `data-~03d.dat`, but that didn't work!

Comment: It would be just hugely better to use exact numbers here rather than relying on how floats get printed

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```scm
(do ((count 111/10 (+ count 1/10))) ((>= count 12))
  (ti-menu-load-string 
   (format #f "file read-data data-~2,3F.dat" count)))
```

I assume `format` is from [SRFI-48 Intermediate Format Strings](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-48/srfi-48.html). I've changed the numbers to rational numbers because adding `0.1` gives you rounding errors in floating point.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have figured that out:

```
data-~.3f.dat
```